# Dev Azure: No code coverage results were found to publish

Tags: spring-boot, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, jacoco

I'm trying to see my code coverage in my pipeline summary
[image: 68 passing tests]

project details: Java spring

Error: ##[warning]No code coverage results were found to publish.

Pipeline:

```
- task: Maven@3
    displayName: Maven SoftwareEngineeringBackend/pom.xml
    inputs:
      mavenPOMFile: $(BuildParameters.mavenPOMFile)
      goals: "test"
  - task: PublishTestResults@2
    displayName: "Publish test results"
    inputs:
      testResultsFormat: "JUnit"
      mergeTestResults: true
  - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
    inputs:
      summaryFileLocation: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml'
      pathToSources: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/main/java/'
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly check if you have added the Jacoco plugin in your Pom.xml or not. If added then add configuration for it to enable XML report i.e `xml.enabled true`.

After mvn build process is finished go to the build or target directory and find the path of XML report most probably it will be `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml` for Gradle and  `{System.DefaultWorkingDirectory}/**/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml for Maven`

Reference -

1. https://iamvickyav.medium.com/code-coverage-report-with-jacoco-in-azure-devops-pipeline-395558712977
2. https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/reporting-code-coverage-using-maven-and-jacoco-plugin/